# pst-barcode with pstool

Tags: pdftex, auto-pst-pdf, pst-barcode, pstool

I would like to use the package pst-barcode with pstool. 
Is this possible?

I am aware of the working pdflatex solution:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf,pst-barcode}
\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}(1in,1in)
    \psbarcode{http://example.org}{eclevel=L}{qrcode}
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

but due to other reasons I need to use the pstool package and I cannot figure out how auto-pst-pdf and pstool can work together.

Comment: From the documentation of `pstool`: “At present this package is designed solely as a replacement for `pst-pdf` in the rôle of supporting the `psfrag` package (which it loads) in pdfLaTeX.”

Comment: Thanks egreg. The problem is that I cannot use pstool and auto-pst-pdf packege at the same time

Answer (score 2):

After loading `auto-pdt-pdf` set the command `\psfragfig` to `\relax` then `pstool` can define it in its own way:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}
\let\psfragfig\relax
\usepackage[process=all]{pstool}
\usepackage{pst-barcode}
\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}(1in,1in)
    \psbarcode{http://example.org}{eclevel=L}{qrcode}
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

However, `pstool` is not really a complete replacement for the package `auto-pst-pdf`!